# VS debugging shows null for nullable DateTime

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am using .NET 3.5. I was debugging a piece of code in Visual Studio and found that the debugger shows null for a DateTime? variable, which just got assigned. This had me confused for sometime. Later when I printed the value it starts showing the value. Is there some tweak to have the actual value shown right away ?

[image]

```
public class MyClass {
    public DateTime? ActualStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ScheduledStart { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing I can see wrong with the code you've pasted. Can you paste the definition for `MyClass` as well?

Comment: It looks like the issue would be with MyClass indeed. Just for fun - have you tried to `new` your nullable? instead of just assigning a DateTime to it? Also - have you tried just adding DateTime.Now to it without going through MyClass just to verify?

Comment: @AshwinNair I have added the code for `MyClass` . @Allan, I assigned DateTime.Now and it shows up with value.